# Riddle me this , Riddle me that

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> In my place time has stopped
>
> time may fly but I will never grow old
>
> I am used as evidence of the past
>
> people may mention me with pride or disgust
>
> I am not the one to blame, to what I was born to be
>
> but the person who pulled the trigger, gave birth to me.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE and good first puzzle! If you are interested in learning more about this site (and getting another badge) check out the tour from this link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> a photograph

In my place time has stopped
time may fly but i will never grow old

> We get older, but our pictures stay the same age.

I am used as evidence of the past
people may mention me with pride or discussed

> Pictures can be shown to others as evidence of what happened.

I am not the one to blame , to what i was born to be
but the person who pulled the trigger , gave birth to me.

> A photograph's author is the person who pushes the button.

Comment: That was really quick!!! And you are absolutely right!!!